# Cell phone privacy

Tags: smartphone, geolocation, cellular

I keep hearing about cell phone tracking, but I always wondered how common is it? Is it something that only 3 letter agencies can do or is it something pretty common?
I've seen those websites that promise you reverse number lookup along with name and recent location for a few bucks but that can't be true right?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse number lookup usually is based on data collected from users or organizations from various medium.

Cell phone tracking is possible. There is another 3 letter term known as SS7 which may be what you are enquiring on.

SS7 is a set of protocols allowing phone networks to exchange information for passing calls and text messages between each other and to ensure correct billing. It also allows users on one network to roam on another when you are overseas.

Hackers can track mobile phone users’ locations with just the knowledge of their phone number using SS7 vulnerability. Of course not limited to that, they can also read text messages and listen to phone calls and more.

There is no way of avoiding being tracked unless you turn your phone off. Worse is that all they need is just your mobile number and there's really nothing much you can do.

What is being done now is that operators are monitoring the networks, looking for intrusions or abuse of the signalling system. For users, i suppose next best thing is follow security best practices. Don't jailbreak/root your phone, don't download from unlicensed stores etc.